# Vuejs combine array child's as an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have such data:

[image: one]

## Logic

1. Returned data has sub-data (array) named `links`
2. Each link has child named `closures`
3. I need to return these `closures` as of an array at once.

## Code

```
axios.post('/api/valChanger', {[val]: e})
  .then(res => {
    this.closures = res.data.data.links.closures;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    //...
  });
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rest operator for this case:

```
axios.post('/api/valChanger', {[val]: e})
  .then(res => {
    let links = res.data.links;
    for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
       this.closures = [...this.closures, ...links[i].closures]
    }

  })
  .catch(error => {
    //...
  });
```

Comment: i get red line error under `...,` parts  https://ibb.co/p4GnNzk

Comment: only at `this.closures...`?

Comment: shared screenshot

Comment: oh sorry what a dumb mistake, the points need to be infront of the variable i edited my answer

Comment: yes i already did that but i guess this is the correct one `this.closures = [...links[i].closures]` i don't need to repeat my closures inside my closures again right?

Comment: no because if you do it like this `this.closures = [...links[i].closures]` after every loop you will set a new value to your `this.closures` property value.

Comment: yes that's what i want :) the closure list gets update based on selected option in other select box

Comment: well than thats ok